# cannot switch project to another Visual Studio Online Account

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I have a project. I made a new visual studio online account, which I can see in team explorer. I did follow the above link instructions to unbind project from old VSO account.

Now when I go to bind it. It tries to bind it to the old VSO account, and I have no way to tell him to bind to the new one. ( I delete the old TFS folder manually, but it did not help )

Any idea ? Or shall I re create a project and copy paste files and folders one by one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likley still have a workspace mapped to the old VSO account in the registry.

Run "tf workspaces" to see a full list of workspaces. Then use "tf workspace" to delete the old entries.

Once done you should map to the new VSO and try the unmap/remap again.